# DirextX Game Syntax Error

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

Ey,

I need some little help with my game. I'm trying to change the gamestate in the intro class but it gives alot of errors.

Intro.h

```
#pragma once
#include "SpriteBatch.h"
#include "GameState.h"

class Intro
{
public:
    Intro();
    ~Intro();

    void Update(GameState* gameState);
    void Draw(DirectX::SpriteBatch* spriteBatch);

private:

    float _timer = 0.0f;
};
```

Intro.cpp

```
#include "Intro.h"
#include "LoadContent.h"
#include "SimpleMath.h"


Intro::Intro()
{
    LoadContent::InitIntro();
    if (!LoadContent::isLoaded("Block"))
        LoadContent::LoadTexture(L"Images/Block.dds", "Block");
}


Intro::~Intro()
{
}

void Intro::Update(GameState* gameState)
{
    if (_timer < 10)
        _timer += 0.1;
    else
        gameState->SwitchState(GameState::ScreenType::MenuScreen);
}

void Intro::Draw(DirectX::SpriteBatch* spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch->Draw(LoadContent::GetTexture("Block"), DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector2(170, 196), DirectX::Colors::White);
}
```

GameState.h

```
#pragma once
#include "SpriteBatch.h"
#include "Menu.h"
#include "SwitchScreen.h"
#include "Intro.h"

class GameState
{
public:
    GameState();
    ~GameState();

    void Update();
    void Draw(DirectX::SpriteBatch* spriteBatch, DirectX::SpriteFont* spriteFont);

public:

    enum ScreenType{Direct, MenuScreen, Game};

private:

    ScreenType _screenType;
    Intro* _screen;
    Menu* _menu;
    SwitchScreen* _switch;

public:
    void GameState::SwitchState(ScreenType switchtype);

};
```

GameState.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "GameState.h"


GameState::GameState()
{
    _switch = new SwitchScreen();
    _screenType = ScreenType::Direct;
    SwitchState(_screenType);
}


GameState::~GameState()
{
}

void GameState::Update()
{
    _switch->Update();

    switch (_screenType)
    {
    case GameState::Direct:
        _screen->Update(this);
        break;
    case GameState::MenuScreen:
        _menu->Update();
        break;
    case GameState::Game:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}


void GameState::Draw(DirectX::SpriteBatch* spriteBatch, DirectX::SpriteFont* spriteFont)
{
    switch (_screenType)
    {
    case GameState::Direct:
        _screen->Draw(spriteBatch);
        break;
    case GameState::MenuScreen:
        _menu->Draw(spriteBatch, spriteFont);
        break;
    case GameState::Game:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    _switch->Draw(spriteBatch);
}

void GameState::SwitchState(ScreenType switchtype)
{
    if (!_switch->GetUpdate())
    {
        _switch = new SwitchScreen();
    }
    else {
        if (_switch->GetUpdate())
        {
            _screen = NULL;
            _menu = NULL;

            switch (switchtype)
            {
            case GameState::Direct:
                _screen = new Intro();
                break;
            case GameState::MenuScreen:
                _menu = new Menu();
                break;
            case GameState::Game:
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            //_switch->SetSwitch(false);
        }
    }
}
```

> Error 1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier
>   'GameState'   \jelly\intro.h  11
>
> Error 2   error C2061: syntax error : identifier
>   'GameState'   \jelly\intro.h  11
>
> Error 6   error C2061: syntax error : identifier
>   'GameState'   \jelly\intro.h  11
>
> Error 3   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before
>   '*'   \jelly\gamestate.h  23
>
> Error 7   error C2660:
>   'Intro::Update' : function does not take 1
>   arguments \jelly\gamestate.cpp    24
>
> Error 4   error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int   \jelly\gamestate.h  23
>
> Warning   5   warning C4305: '+='
>   : truncation from 'double' to
>   'float'   \jelly\intro.cpp    21

Thank you

Comment: Looks like a circular include issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a circular include issue.

You should try just forward declaring `GameState` in your `Intro.h` header file

**`Intro.h`**

```
#include "SpriteBatch.h"
// #include "GameState.h" <<< Nope!
class GameState; // Do this instead
```

instead of including `GameState.h` in `Intro.h`.

Include `GameState.h` in `Intro.cpp` accordingly, to have the full fledged class declaration seen there:

**`Intro.cpp`**

```
#include "Intro.h"
#include "LoadContent.h"
#include "SimpleMath.h"
#include "Gamestate.h" // <<<<
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You don't need `GameState.h` in `Intro.h`.

**`Intro.h`**

```
#pragma once
#include "SpriteBatch.h"
//#include "GameState.h" -> remove this

class GameState; //Add this line - forward declaration is enough to declare a pointer.
```

**2.** Add include of `GameState.h` to `Intro.cpp`.

**`Intro.cpp`**

```
#include "Intro.h"
#include "LoadContent.h"
#include "SimpleMath.h"
#include "GameState.h" //add this
```

**3.** You don't need `Intro.h` in `GameState.h`.

**`GameState.h`**

```
#pragma once
#include "SpriteBatch.h"
#include "Menu.h"
#include "SwitchScreen.h"
//#include "Intro.h" -> remove this

class Intro; //Add this line - forward declaration is enough to declare a pointer.
```

**4.** Add include of `Intro.h` to `GameState.cpp`.

**`GameState.cpp`**

```
#pragma once
#include "GameState.h"
#include "Intro.h" //add this
```

**5.** The biggest issue.

In `GameState` class, change:

```
public:
  void GameState::SwitchState(ScreenType switchtype);
```

to

```
public:
  void SwitchState(ScreenType switchtype);
```

This is the thing, that your compiler is probably complaining about.